# Am I correctly running python cronjob on hourly basis on Linux

Tags: python, cron

```
0 */1 * * * /home/jhon/virtual_env/bin/python /home/jhon/COVID-19\ tracker\ design/state_data.py > india.log
```

My program in running under virtual env. So I have initiated the job using virtual env python i.e. `/home/jhon/virtual_env/bin/python`

When I check the COVID folder, `india.log` file does not generate. Also cronjob is not executing on hourly basis.

Is there anything wrong here?

When I execute command `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`

It gives  log like this

```
Apr 10 23:17:01 di-2020-feb-john-1 CRON[22100]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Apr 11 00:00:01 di-2020-feb-john-1 CRON[22683]: (jhon) CMD (/home/jhon/virtual_env/bin/python /home/jhon/COVID-19\ tracker\ design/state_wise_data.py > india.log)
Apr 11 00:17:01 di-2020-feb-john-1 CRON[22891]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Apr 11 01:00:01 di-2020-feb-john-1 CRON[23464]: (jhon) CMD (/home/jhon/virtual_env/bin/python /home/jhon/COVID-19\ tracker\ design/state_wise_data.py > india.log)
Apr 11 01:17:01 di-2020-feb-john-1 CRON[23680]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Apr 11 02:00:01 di-2020-feb-john-1 CRON[24257]: (jhon) CMD (/home/jhon/virtual_env/bin/python /home/jhon/COVID-19\ tracker\ design/state_wise_data.py > india.log)
Apr 11 02:17:01 di-2020-feb-john-1 CRON[24510]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Apr 11 03:00:01 di-2020-feb-john-1 CRON[25109]: (jhon) CMD (/home/jhon/virtual_env/bin/python /home/jhon/COVID-19\ tracker\ design/state_wise_data.py > india.log)
Apr 11 03:01:01 di-2020-feb-john-1 CRON[25127]: (root) CMD (   test -x /etc/cron.daily/popularity-contest && /etc/cron.daily/popularity-contest --crond)
Apr 11 03:17:01 di-2020-feb-john-1 CRON[25358]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Apr 11 04:00:01 di-2020-feb-john-1 CRON[26333]: (jhon) CMD (/home/jhon/virtual_env/bin/python /home/jhon/COVID-19\ tracker\ design/state_wise_data.py > india.log)
Apr 11 04:17:01 di-2020-feb-john-1 CRON[26546]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Apr 11 05:00:01 di-2020-feb-john-1 CRON[27141]: (jhon) CMD (/home/jhon/virtual_env/bin/python /home/jhon/COVID-19\ tracker\ design/state_wise_data.py > india.log)
Apr 11 05:17:01 di-2020-feb-john-1 CRON[27382]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not experienced with linux, but why do you alternate between forward and back slashes in your file path? I imagine that would cause problems, along with the spaces you have in there.

Also, for a pure python alternative to cron check out [schedule](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

hope this helps!

Comment: It due to `space` in folder name. That is why it has backward slash